# Notify Author of the post if admin deletes his post and perform some function

Tags: posts, author, functions

i am working on a theme in which points are added in user meta when he does a post... it works fine but the problem is when a post is deleted by the admin then the point should be reduced and the author should get intimation . The main problem is getting the author id of the post and doing function after the post is deleted....

the code i am trying is

```
function deletePointFromUser($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
$authorid = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts WHERE post_id = $post_ID');
$currentPointNumber = get_usermeta($authorid, 'points');

//Delete 1 to the current Point Score
$newPointNumber = $currentPointNumber - 1;  
update_usermeta( $authorid, 'points', $newPointNumber); 
 }
add_action('deleted_post', 'deletePointFromUser');
```

Comment: this looks about right , what is the problem/question?

Comment: The get_var call needs double quotes, else that post id is getting treated literally as $post_id and not the numeric value it contains, which is probably why you're not getting back the expected author id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it's better to user WP functions than write your own SQL. Even though it might be a bit more expensive:

```
$post = get_post($post_ID);
$authorid = $post->post_author;
```

Secondly, it's not `get_usermeta()`, but `get_user_meta()` and the complete call should include `true` as the third parameter:

```
$currentPointNumber = get_user_meta($authorid, 'points', true);
```

And then it's `update_user_meta()`, again, and you don't need to initialize a new variable, just do:

```
update_user_meta($authorid, 'points', $currentPointNumber-1);
```

Comment: Just a note, there is a `get_usermeta` function, but it was deprecated since WP 3.0 and was replaced by `get_user_meta`, so technically the existing code wasn't incorrect, simply calling a deprecated function.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly fine .... and get_usermeta() is a function , it was deprecated since wordpress 3.0 with get_user_meta() and same goes for update_usermeta.

Comment: Yepp, thanks...was a bit hasty with my lecturing, there. ;-)